# How to crawl an Angular JS web app?

Tags: python, angularjs, selenium, web-crawler, scrapy

I am trying to crawl a web app which has login as the first hurdle and is built on angular js. I was using scrapy and selenium to crawl the website but there is a problem with logging in. I have this post where I asked for help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30926880/what-is-the-best-way-for-crawling-with-scrapy-and-selenium-angularjs-website but I didn't get any help. The problem is when I use selenium(shown below) for reading the innerHTML of the body element it is giving me blank response. Why is it so? Is it because of HTTPS or because any other permission issues?

Also if some one can help me with how to use both scrapy and selenium along with login and cookies to scrap a website. That will be really helpful.

```
def crawl_url(url, run_headless=True):
    if run_headless:
        display = Display(visible=0, size=(1024, 768))
        display.start()

    url = correct_url(url)
    browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(service_args=['--load-images=no'])
    login_url = "https://domain.com/login"
    browser.get(login_url)
    time.sleep(15)
    element = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body')
    print element.get_attribute('innerHTML')
```

Comment: Can you share a link to the website?

Comment: Is the innerHTML being set by javascript, so that it doesn't appear at the beginning when selenium is reading it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhantomJS is known to have problems with Angular and it is recommended that you use Chrome instead. You can install chromedriver from https://devblog.supportbee.com/2014/10/27/setting-up-cucumber-to-run-with-Chrome-on-Linux/ and replace

```
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(service_args=['--load-images=no'])
```

with

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
```

and then this should work. You can alternatively use a framework called Protractor which is specifically used to test Angular pages and it knows how to run and parse the JavaScript to get out the html. It has a webdriverjs wrapper built upon selenium.